# Is there a good way to something may be required if something else is not provided?

Tags: expressions

Is there a better way to state the following:

Column C must be provided if neither column A or column B are provided.

I am trying to find a way that simply and quickly expresses when something is required versus when it is optional for users that may not be reading carefully and for users who may not have English as a first language.

Comment: The version you presented seems clear enough. You can also say “... if (...) are absent”.

Answer (score 1):

"In the absence of A or B, C can be used instead."

But what you have is fairly clear as well.

Comment: Also "in lieu of."